Why does the Password App in macOS show my personal iCloud icon for a website?
I have added two entries for separate accounts with the same organization.

One entry has the icon for the organization
The other entry has my personal iCloud icon.

I don’t necessarily want a custom icon. I can’t see why one entry has my own iCloud icon when I have entered the same web site as the other.
I’ve edit everything I can find to ensure the details are complete, including the web site. I can’t find any way, however, of editing the icon.
Is it possible to alter the icon the macOS password app assigns to an entry?
PS: This may seem similar to How to change the icon displayed in the password.app, but there they want to set a custom icon. I just want Password to pick up the default.

This question is similar to: How to change the icon displayed in the password.app. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jaume Actually, it appears to be the opposite. That question wants a different icon from the one from the web site. I’ll edit my question.
